# Vaadin doubles the name of my widgetset

Tags: java, maven, vaadin

I have a Maven Vaadin project with a custom widgetset in the folder `src/main/resources/CustomWidgetset`. However, when I do `mvn -Pcompile-widgetset package`, the widgetset somehow ends up in `src/main/webapp/VAADIN/widgetsets/CustomWidgetset.CustomWidgetset` (CustomWidgetset twice with a "." in between) and then can't find it:

```
Information: Requested resource [VAADIN/widgetsets/CustomWidgetset/CustomWidgetset.nocache.js] not found from filesystem or through class loader. Add widgetset and/or theme JAR to your classpath or add files to WebContent/VAADIN folder.
```

Can you tell me, where *exactly* I have to put my widgetset so that it gets 100% recognized, compiled and found later on?

**Solution**
I found out, I had the wrong param-name and it works now by replacing

```
<param-name>org.mypackage.CustomWidgetset</param-name>
```

with

```
<param-name>widgetset</param-name>
```

Although I don't understand why there was no error thrown.

**P.S.**
That wasn't enough, I also had to move `src/main/resources/CustomWidgetset/CustomWidgetset.gwt.xml` to `src/main/resources/CustomWidgetset.gwt.xml`. Apparently a widgetset isn't expected to have its own folder so all the widgetsets reside directly in the package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the standard Maven archetypes for Vaadin, the right place for the widgetset is the folder where it ends up when you compile it - `src/main/webapp/VAADIN/widgetsets`. I don't know why you have it in `src/main/resources`.

What the name of the compiled widgetset will be depends of the name of your GWT module descriptor. That is a .gwt.xml file somewhere in your project. It should be named `CustomWidgetset.gwt.xml` in your case, but is it possibly `CustomWidgetset.CustomWidgetset.gwt.xml` for some reason?

Then to the next thing, where Vaadin tries to find your compiled widgetset. It will look for a parameter in your servlet descriptor to see which widgetset it should use.

If you use Servlet API 2.X, then you would have a web.xml file under `webapp/WEB-INF` and within that you'll find

```
<init-param>
<param-name>widgetset</param-name>
<param-value>com.example.CustomWidgetset.CustomWidgetset</param-value>
</init-param>
```

If you use Servlet API 3.0, then your UI class will have a servlet definition that would look like this.

```
@WebServlet(value = "/*", asyncSupported = true)
@VaadinServletConfiguration(productionMode = false, ui = AppUI.class, widgetset = "com.example.CustomWidgetset.CustomWidgetset")
public static class Servlet extends VaadinServlet {
}
```

Either, 2.X or 3.0, the cure is the same - remove the extra `.CustomWidgetset` from it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I hope that it will help but can only check on Monday. The src/main/resources is because I use maven and it automatically copies the files from there to the webapp folder (+ some more magic that I don't understand.